# Python on merging dataframe rename columns by dictionaries keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Initially, I have an empty dataframe with date field and later I am trying to merge it with the new dataframe in a for loop.

```
com_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])
    for i in data_dict.values():
        response = requests.get('www.example.com/' + i + '?format=json')
        data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
        df = dataframe_format(data[1]) // convert list of dict to dataframe
        com_df = pd.merge(com_df, df, on='date', how='outer')
```

So the output for now is like,

```
    date       value_x       value_y  value_x     value_y       value
0   2017  1.722333e+13  8.711267e+12   3485.0  197.713256   46.030025
1   2016  1.829506e+13  7.320738e+12   3052.0  249.907289   -2.024998
2   2015  3.932602e+13  8.188019e+12   2827.0  480.287296   -6.007182
```

But I want the column name to be the keys of below dictionary,

```
data_dict = {'A': '1','B': '2','C': '3','D': '4','E': '5'}
```

that is,

```
    date           A              B        C            D       E 
0   2017  1.722333e+13  8.711267e+12   3485.0  197.713256   46.030025
1   2016  1.829506e+13  7.320738e+12   3052.0  249.907289   -2.024998
2   2015  3.932602e+13  8.188019e+12   2827.0  480.287296   -6.007182
```

Comment: In general, dictionary keys are not sorted in Python. How do you know that the second column should be 'A'? Is there another criterion? Or do you want to order the keys by their values?

Comment: something like this shoul work `com_df.columns = list(data_dict.keys())`

Comment: @VageEgiazarian As I said above, in general, dictionary keys are not sorted in Python.

Comment: @DYZ  why should it be sorted? If you want sorted `com_df.columns = list(data_dict.keys()).sort()`

Comment: @VageEgiazarian `list(data_dict.keys())` is allowed to report the keys in any order. I am not sure whether that's what the OP wants. I am not even sure they want the keys to be sorted alphabetically because for that, there is no need to define a dictionary, a list would suffice.

Comment: @VageEgiazarian As a side note, they want to preserve the name of the first column.

Comment: @DYZ you are right.  Vipul Singhcan you give more detail what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to apply the dictionary keys sorted by their values, then you can do this:

```
df.columns = [df.columns[0]] \
           + [k for k,_ in sorted(data_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

Comment: Thanks @DYZ but here values can be any character also so there no chance of sort by value

Comment: Then how do you want the yes sorted?

Answer (score 0):

I would transform your input dictionary to one mapping index to column name:

```
data_dict = {'A': '1','B': '2','C': '3','D': '4','E': '5'}
pos_col_dict = {int(v): k for k, v in data_dict.items()}
```

Then assign to columns via NumPy. You should use a copy to avoid side-effects:

```
arr = df.columns.values
arr[list(pos_col_dict)] = list(pos_col_dict.values())
df.columns = arr
```

Comment: But my dictionaries values can be text also say,{ 'A': 'hello', 'Z':'hi',.}

Comment: That's not clear at all. What do the values represent if not position? Dictionaries are considered unordered (unless you use Python 3.7+).